# What is the name of the operation when you do a Kronecker tensor square without repeated combination of products?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, kronecker-product

let's say I have a tensor:

`A = [3, 5, 7]`

If I do a Kronecker product of `A` with `A` I would get the tensor `[9,15,21,15,25,35,21,35,49]`

One can notice that `15` appear twice since the `1st 3`x`2nd 5` are the same as `1st 5`x`2nd 3` (also `21` & `35`).

I want to know if there is a name for an equivalent operation to square the tensor without repeated elements so the result tensor would be `[9, 15, 21, 25, 35, 49]`.

Comment: Reminds me of Voigt notation a little bit: your Kronecker product is like an outer product, which would give a symmetric matrix. You only want the upper triangular half of it (skipping the symmetric equivalents). That is what [Voigt notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voigt_notation) does though for full rank matrices. Not exactly what you wanted, but related.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's not a special name for this, but it amounts to
dropping the $(4,7,8)^{th}$ rows from the vector.
And there is an algebraic expression for such an operation
$$\eqalign{
&b = M(a\otimes a) \\
&M=\left[\matrix{
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
}\right]
}$$
where each row of $M$ contains a single ${\tt1}\,$ while its $(4,7,8)^{th}$ columns are zeros.

More generally, if $a\in{\mathbb R}^{n}$,
then $M\in{\mathbb R}^{(n^2+n)/2\,\times n^2}\,$ and the zero columns are at
$$\eqalign{
&1n+1 \\
&2n+1,\quad 2n+2 \\
&3n+1,\quad 3n+2,\quad 3n+3 \\
&4n+1,\quad 4n+2,\quad \ldots \\
&\ldots\\
&(n-1)n+1,\;(n-1)n+2,\quad \ldots,\quad &n^2-1
}$$